# WPF Application that runs selenium tests

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, selenium

Hi is there a way that I could create a WPF application which acts as the front end for my selenium test scripts. I have created regression tests using selenium and I was wondering if I could create a WPF application which would allow me to set parameters for tests and then run it from the same application? I usually run the tests from visual studio and it would be awesome if there was a way to create an application to run them instead

Comment: In case you are using NUnit there is a [GUI runner](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.2.10) that can do that for you.

Comment: @ekostadinov Yeah that is basically what I want but I want to create my own with my own styling.

Comment: You can use [this github repo](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui) as a starting point.

Comment: @ekostadinov thank you do you know if there would be a way to run the tests from a website, so instead of a desktop application I could run the tests directly from my website using NUnit

Answer (score 0):

To sum up all the comments - since you are using NUnit there is a [GUI runner](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.2.10) that can do that for you. Depending on what UI you want to put as top layer, there are [Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx) and [ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx).

Here is [how I did it](https://github.com/ekostadinov/BitCI/blob/master/BitCI/Models/BuildSteps/RunTestsStep.cs#L41-L51) with the later one:

```
var db = new ServerContext();
Build build = db.Builds.Find(BuildId);
var project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(build.ProjectId));
string value = Value;
string gitDirrectory = Build.Workspace.Replace("\\", "/") + "/source";

//run NUnit tests
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c "+ gitDirrectory + @"/packages/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/nunit-console.exe " + gitDirrectory
        + value 
        + " /include:" + project.Name.Replace(" team", String.Empty).Trim()
        + " >> " + Build.Log;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Feel free to use any part of the repo's code you find useful.